# how to get lable of related model in Yii CDetailView?

Tags: yii

Is there any way to access relative model lable? Here w_experience is defined in worker and because $model has not this lable, W Experience appears instead of worker model value!

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView',
    array( 'data'=>$model, 
    'attributes'=>array( 
        array('name'=>'w_experience', 'value'=>$model->worker->w_experience==NULL?'-':$GLOBALS['worker_experience_options'][$model->worker->w_experience]),
        ), 
    'cssFile' => Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl."/css/darktable.css", )
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried `'name' => 'worker.w_experience'` ?

Comment: Thank You. it Worked. Please add it as Answer Yourself. It may help another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
array(
  'name' => 'worker.w_experience',
  'value' => ...
),
```

where `worker` is the name of your relation.

---

Attribute names are usually resolved using `CModel::getAttributeLabel`. If your model is derived from `CActiveRecord`, like all database-backed models are by default, its [`getAttributeLabel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getAttributeLabel-detail) implementation can fetch labels from related objects like this.